# Adding "*" when statistic difference to ggplot2 with R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to add "*" to each point in one graph when there is a significant decrease from baseline.
I represent the median along time in 40 groups: 8 different MIC and 5 different eGFR.

The code can be reproduced using:

```
time <-rep(c(0,24,48,72,96,120,144,168,192,216,240), times=40)
MIC <- rep(c(0.125, 0.5, 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32),each=11,length.out=440)
eGFR <- rep(c("0-30","30-60","60-90","90-120","120-150"),each=88,length.out=440)
median <- runif(440)
db1 <- data.frame(time, MIC, eGFR, median)

ggplot(data=db1, aes(x=time/24, y=median, color = as.factor(MIC)))  +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point(size=0.75) +
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("#669999", "green", "blue", "orange", "#9933FF", "red", "brown", "#660000")) +
  facet_grid(.~eGFR, scales = "free") +
  labs(x = "Time (days)", y = "Conc (mg/dL)", color = "MIC (mg/L)") +
  scale_x_log10()
```

From the data, I did an anova test then the Tuckey test to know if the difference between the 40 subgroups were significant or not.
I used this kind of code (here for MIC = 0.125 and eGFR = 0-30 but I did it for all 40 groups)

```
db0.125_030 <- db1 %>%
   filter(MIC == 0.125) %>%
   filter(eGFR == "0-30")
aov1 <- aov(median ~ time, db0.125_030) 
TukeyHSD(aov1)
```

I tried to use `stat_compare_means()` to add automatically the "*" or `annotate()` to do it manually (ouch!) by adding it to my plot code, but it doesn't work.

Any idea of what I could do please? Should I add a column in db1 significant "yes, no"? I don't know what I could try...

Thank you!

Edit:
The following code works for my purpose, but I had to put manually if p was significant or not

```
ggplot(data=dbless10d, 
       aes(x=time/24, y=median, color = as.factor(MIC)))+ 
  geom_line()+ 
  geom_point(size=0.75)+ 
  facet_grid(.~eGFR, scales = "free"))+ 
  labs(color = "MIC (mg/L)")+ 
  geom_text(data = db1[db1$significant == 1, ],
            aes(x = time/24, y = median),
            label = "*",size = 5,nudge_y = 0.3,show.legend = FALSE)
```

Comment: Please edit the code formatting and maybe summarise the question?

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I would like to add a symbol (*) to all points of 4 scatter plots (splat by facet_grid) whenever I got significant p-value from a statistical test but I don't know what I can do...